# In Scala, how can i declare right type in base abstract class to access by index in this situation

Tags: scala, oop

I'm sorry, I'm very new to Scala.

My code looks like below.

```
abstract class A{
  val container: Any
  //Some other member and methods are hidden
}

class B extends A {
  val container: Vector(1,2)
  //Some other member and methods are hidden
}

class C extends A {
  val container: ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)
  //Some other member and methods are hidden
}
```

So, when i want use these function in main function like below, which means that i intend  to access **container** by index.

```
val vector = new ArrayBuffer[A].empty
vector += new B
vector += new C
  
for( vec <- vector ){
  println(vec.container(0))
}
```

However, the compiler says "Any does not take parameters"

So, my problem is, how should i declare value **container** in base class to access input with index.

Help me, Thanks.

Comment: What scala version do you use?

Comment: Thank you for reading it, my Scala version is "2.13.8"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 variants:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector
import scala.collection.IndexedSeq

// variant 1
trait A1[T] {
  def container: IndexedSeq[T]
}

class B1 extends A1[Int] {
  val container: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2)
}

class C1 extends A1[Long] {
  val container: Vector[Long] = Vector(1, 2)
}

// variant 2
trait A2 {
  def container: IndexedSeq[_]
}

class B2 extends A2 {
  val container: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2)
}

class C2 extends A2 {
  val container: ArrayBuffer[Long] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2)
}

object Main extends App {
  val coll1 = new ArrayBuffer[A1[_]]()
  coll1 += new B1()
  coll1 += new C1()
  val coll2 = new ArrayBuffer[A2]()
  coll2 += new B2()
  coll2 += new C2()
  
  for( vec <- coll1 ) {
    println(vec.container(0))
  }
  for( vec <- coll2 ) {
    println(vec.container(0))
  }
}
```

tested [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-scala-online) on Scala 2.13.6

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! I tried to test your answer code in my personal environment. However, compiler says "Overriding type ArrayBuffer[Long] does not conform to base type IndexedSeq[_]".

Comment: try to add imports: `import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.immutable.Vector
import scala.collection.IndexedSeq`. It work without imports on Scala 2.12 (only ArrayBuffer import required)

Comment: It works!!!, i really appreciate your efforts.